# How to derive a portable seed from Python's random.getstate()?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I frequently use arbitrary string-based seeds with Python's built-in `random` module to produce RNGs with known, repeatable states. Of course, `random.getstate()` and `random.setstate()` are useful for saving and restoring the state of an RNG, but the actual state values are unwieldy.

**Is there a way to derive a <del>string</del> *seed value* from a state that, when provided to `random.seed()`, produces an RNG in the same state as the equivalent call to `random.setstate()`?**

That is, given the following code:

```py
>>> import random

>>> random.seed('foo')

>>> state = random.getstate()

>>> random.random()
0.45443115919715416

>>> random.setstate(state)

>>> random.random()
0.45443115919715416

>>> derived_seed = derive_seed(state)

>>> random.seed(derived_seed)

>>> random.random()
0.45443115919715416

>>> print(derived_seed)
<insert derived seed value here... is it an int? a str?>
```

How would you implement the above `derive_seed()` function?

---

**UPDATE:** `random.Random().seed()` has a [Python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/random.py#L128-L168) which converts the `str` to an `int`, and a [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/204946986feee7bc80b233350377d24d20fcb1b8/Modules/_randommodule.c#L274-L355) which converts the integer seed into a byte array. It seems like this process could be reversed to take the state back to a string, but I'm not confident at this level of Python internals.

**UPDATE 2:** Because of the hashing involved in processing a `str` or `bytes` seed value, it doesn't appear that there's a way to reverse engineer a string value from a state. I hold out hope that it's possible to reverse engineer an integer value though.

Comment: Define "reasonable". Is `hash(state)` reasonable? I doubt you can `random.seed(derived_seed)` and get the same value if `derived_seed != 'foo'`

Comment: `hash(state)` would be reasonable, except for not working. :)